# axios cors problem when using request interceptor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js

I'm having a problem with axios interceptor. I'm trying to call a public API and send a header (only for test) and when I use a request interceptor, my request have the response as a CORS error. But if I don't use interceptor, the request works fine.

In my axios config file I have something like this:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://randomfox.ca/floof'
})

api.interceptors.request.use(
  function (config) {
    config.headers.test = 'I am only a header!'
    return config
  },
  function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
)

export default api
```

I'm using NextJS and in my component I have something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import api from 'services/HTTPService'

export default function MyComponent() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    api.get('/')
  }, [])

  return null
}
```

Comment: Might be related to the custom header you're setting in the interceptor. `TEST` header is probably not part of the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in the server response, triggering the CORS error.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes. I created an Axios Instance. And exported this instance with the interceptors (checking if instance already exists). So in every API call, I used getAxiosInstance().post('my-url/something')...